# Magento - Track and save changes to products' prices

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way (embedded in Magento or with a module) to track and persistently record changes to products' prices?

For example, what if i wanted to know precisely in the last year how the price of a specific product (or of a set of products) was changed by the admins?

I don't want to write custom code for this, only to know if something like this exists or not...i tried to search around but didn't find anything close to it.

Thanks

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to write code for this, but for what its worth, writing an event observer to log this sort of thing to a file would be fairly simple, if you do end up going that route.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mike, but i was specifically asked to find out if this functionality already existed. The answer was "no", and now i'm waiting to know if i have to write code for it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no that is not part of the magento core